# Variable inputs Recurrent Neural Network in Keras

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have two datasets, both have a lot of rows, for each row I have in the first dataset 10 columns (extracted features) in the second dataset I have 18 columns(features extracted).
Now I would like to train a Recurrent Neural Network (in Keras) with both datasets but having different `input_size` (the columns). This is my code:

```
time_steps = 1  # the height of the image
input_size = 10  # extracted features dataset 1
BATCH_SIZE = 1
num_class = 7 
model = Sequential()

# RNN cell
model.add(LSTM(batch_input_shape=(BATCH_SIZE, time_steps, input_size), 
units=n_hidden_units, recurrent_dropout=0.3,
               activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid'))
# output layer
model.add(Dense(num_class))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

# optimizer
# adam = Adam(LR)

# compile model
model.compile(optimizer='nadam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(data, target, epochs=25, batch_size=1, verbose=False)

prediction = model.predict_classes(data_test, batch_size=1)
```

The above code is only for the first dataset and how you can see the `input_size=10` is equal to the number of features for dataset one.

My question is how can I do, if I would like to train a Recurrent like above where the `input_size` become variable?

Answer (score 0):

Pad all the sequences to the same length before training. Use zero padding.

Comment: I think you are wrong. data should be given in the format( timesteps, features). Here the time steps is 10 and number of features is 1.